# Multidimensional array declaration

Tags: java, scjp

Which one is valid statement?

1. `int[] x =new int[0]{};`
2. `new int[2];`
3. `int[] x=new int[][]{{1}}[0];`
4. `int[][] x = new int[]{0}[0][0];`
5. `int x= new int[2]{}[];`

The correct answer is 3, and I can understand why it's not 1, 2 or 5, but I don't understand 3 or 4 mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
1) int[] x =new int[0]{};
```

You cannot specify both a length `0` and an array initializer at the same time.

```
2) new int[2];
```

It's not a statement.  It would become a statement if it were assigned to something else, among other possibilities.

```
3) int[] x=new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

This declares and initializes a 1x1 2D array, with `1` being its only element.  Then, array access is used to immediately access the "row" at position 0, the only such "row", which is itself a 1-length 1D array, and that is assigned to a 1D array.

```
4) int[][] x = new int[]{0}[0][0];
```

There is a lot wrong here.  A 1-length, 1D array is created, but there are two array accesses on it.  You can only supply one, because it's a 1D array.

```
5) int x= new int[2]{}[];
```

The extra `[]` doesn't do anything and is invalid syntax.  Even if they're removed, you can't assign an `int` array to a scalar `int`.  Also you can't specify a length and an array initializer `{}` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you declare and initialize an array using `{}` you are not allowed to indicate the number of items in the array ergo `int[0]` should be `int[]`. So it should have been `int[] x = new int[]{}`.
2. This is an initialization without a declaration so it should have been something like `int[] x = new int[2]`.
3. This is correct because it assigns a declaration to an item of two-dimensional array which is an array itself. So the array returned from `new int[][]{{1}}[0]` is `new int[]{1}` and thus `int[] x = new int[]{1}`.
4. This is totally wrong and messed up. `new int[]{0}[0][0]` is trying to get a value of a two-dimensional array from a one-dimensional array and assign that to a the array `x`.
5. Here as discussed already in point 1, plus trying to access an array with an empty index `[]` which not possible.